# Attach images in seed.rb file in rails using active storage

Tags: ruby, rails-activestorage

I have a class called vehicles which can have an image attached to it. I have made a default image to display if no other image was uploaded in the vehicles.rb file.

I would like to include images in the seed.rb file so I don't have to manually upload all images. Is this possible?

Help is much appreciated thanks.

Here is my vehicle.rb:

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :make
  belongs_to :model
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :make
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :model
  has_one_attached :image

  after_commit :add_default_image, on: %i[create update]

  def add_default_image
    unless image.attached?
      image.attach(
        io: File.open(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'no_image_available.jpg')),
        filename: 'no_image_available.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg'
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Here is how i am creating records in my seed file but I would like to include the images as well:

```
v = Vehicle.create(
  vin: '1QJGY54INDG38946',
  color: 'grey',
  make_id: m.id,
  model_id: mo.id,
  wholesale_price: '40,000'
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [Ffaker](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker) gem to easily generate fake data and finally after creating the vehicle record you can update your record image attribute from the instance variable. Check [Attaching File/IO Objects](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects)

This would be the code of `db/seed.rb` file:

```
if Vehicle.count.zero?
  10.times do
    v = Vehicle.create(
      vin: FFaker::Code.ean,
      color: FFaker::Color.name,
      maker_id: m.id,
      model_id: m.id,
      wholesale_price: '40,000'
    )
    v.image.attach(
      io:  File.open(File.join(Rails.root,'app/assets/images/photo.jpg')),
      filename: 'photo.jpg'
    )
  end
end
```

Don't forget to add the ffaker gem to your `Gemfile` file.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi soo i'm trying to enter files for specific records, so I actually have to write the colors and choose an image with the specific color, is there a way to attach different files for each record in the seed.rb?

Comment: can you explain where to put the "file.jpg"?

Comment: I've updated the example, in this case the `photo.jpg` file's path is `app/assets/images/`. You can change the image path deliberately, just make sure that the image exists in the path you entered.

Answer (score 5):

As the above answer states it's in the Edge Guides, for people having trouble getting the path right, this is an example of a line in the `seeds.rb` file attaching an avatar to the 1st created user:

```
User.first.avatar.attach(io: File.open(File.join(Rails.root,'app/assets/images/avatar.jpg')), filename: 'avatar.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me on Rails 7:

- I put my images in public/images folder.
- Seed the DB

###### db/seeds.rb

```
post = Post.create!(title: "My Title", description: "My description")
post.image.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join("public/images/sample.jpg")), filename: "sample.jpg")
```

3. Then in my views:

###### app/views/posts/show.html.erb

```
# to get the image URL:
polymorphic_url(@post.image)

# to display the image
image_tag post.image if post.image.attached?
```

All this assuming you installed ActiveStorage:

In your terminal:

```
$ rails active_storage:install
$ rails db:migrate
```

Then in your model:

###### models/post.rb

```
has_one_attached :image
```

And in your controller. Add image to permitted params:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:image, :everything_else)
```